# What are some common expressions used by gay men in France?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, argot, langage-informel, langage-des-jeunes

I only ask because I am gay. For example, there’s the stereotypical “Girl, stop,” in American English. Or using words like “Honey,” to refer to people and lots of verbal tics and fillers. Are there any expressions or words that are used by a lot of gay men? Maybe ones that come from Twitter or reality TV?

Comment: I wouldn’t know where to look, not being a gay man, and apologies if you’ve already tried, but perhaps francophone forums or blogs catered to gay men might be of use? They should be more centralized, and I’ve found it easy to acquire a basic sense of the vocabulary used (or not used) by various communities this way. It’s particularly useful when it’s less a question of outright jargon.

Answer (score 5):

A few come in mind :

- Grande folle (similar to drama queen, or diva)
- Mon chou (not the literal of cupcake, but definitely the same meaning)
- Mon chéri (honey)
- Ma grande ("my tall", but rather close to "my little one")

Then, as you may (or may not) know, in France we're very vulgar, and there's a lot more that are meaner but are said anyway (results may vary).

Answer (score 1):

You should find [here](https://www.mecamarier.com/glossary/) a rich sample of what the French homosexuals' vocabulary is as pertains to their culture.